# Eigenvalues of the Klein-Gordon operator

Tags: operators, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, klein-gordon-equation

If I've understood what I've read correctly, the eigenvalues of the Klein-Gordon (KG) operator $\Box+m^{2}$ are $-p^{2}+m^{2}$, but how does one show this?

Naively I assumed that the eigenfunctions would be of the form $f_{p}(x)=e^{ip\cdot x}$ (where $p\cdot x=p^{0}x^{0}-\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}$), such that $$(\Box +m^{2})e^{ip\cdot x}=(-p^{2}+m^{2})e^{ip\cdot x}$$however, I feel that I'm missing something here, since clearly $f_{p}(x)=e^{ip\cdot x}$ depends on both $x^{\mu}$ and $p^{\mu}$. Is it simply the continuum analogue of the discrete case, i.e. one may have some operator $A$ acting on a set of eigenvectors $v^{i}$, each with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$, such that(in component form, $$A_{ij}(v^{k})_{j}=\lambda_{k}(v^{k})_{i}$$ (note that the index $i$ is *not* summed over here). Hence, taking the "continuum limit" the index $k$ becomes a continuous parameter $p$, $k\rightarrow p$ and the index $i$ (denoting the components of the eigenvector in the discrete case) becomes another continuous parameter $x$, $i\rightarrow x$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Indeed:

The eigenvalues of a finite dimensional matrix are labelled by an integer. As you posted, there is an eigenvector for each such integer.

In the infinite dimensional case of a differential operator (x is the continuous analogue of the matrix indices i or j) the eigenvalues are labelled by (in this case) real numbers $p^2$. The eigenfunctions are associated to these eigenvalues and so are labelled by p.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59173/discussion-on-answer-by-lux-eigenvalues-of-the-klein-gordon-operator).

Comment: chat "Page Not Found".